# Is there an simulation of MozScrolledAreaChanged event in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

Firefox has an event "MozScrolledAreaChanged" described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Detecting_document_width_and_height_changes).

This event is very useful since it can detect page changes.

Is there a similar way in Chrome or other browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for page changes, you can listen for specific events:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference

```
DOMAttrModified
DOMAttributeNameChanged
DOMCharacterDataModified
DOMElementNameChanged
DOMNodeInserted
DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument
DOMNodeRemoved
DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument
```

Comment: What i want to know is that whether page scroll area is enlarged or not. Can something archive this?